# Recursive function to do a Pyramid Slide in Java

Tags: java, debugging, recursion

I'm having trouble finding a solution to a problem I'm having with a recursive function I've been making and would like to get some insight on how to resolve this.

This is a function I've been making for a CodeWars coding exercize. The point of the exercise is to make a code that can dynamically analyze a "pyramid" (in this case, it's a 2D array) and choose the path with the greatest sum from sliding down those numbers in the pyramid array. Here is my method:

```java
    public static String[] analyzeSlidePath(int[][] pyramid, int drop, int height, int depth, int index,
                                                ArrayList<String[]> possibilities, String[] input, int sum){
            // index gives the current index the slide is at in the pyramid
            // drop gives the height of the pyramid we want the slide to fall
            // height gives the current height the slide is at in the pyramid
            // depth is used to recur this method a certain amount of times
            // possibilities is used to store the potential combinations to use when sliding down
            // sum gives the total amount added during the fall
            if(depth == drop){
                input[drop] = "" + sum; // input has a size of (drop + 1)
                possibilities.add(input);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
            } else { input[depth] = "left";
                analyzeSlidePath(pyramid, drop, height, depth + 1, index, possibilities, input, sum + pyramid[height + depth + 1][index]);
                input[depth] = "right";
                analyzeSlidePath(pyramid, drop, height, depth + 1, index + 1, possibilities, input, sum + pyramid[height + depth + 1][index + 1]);
            } int lastMaxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int lastMaxIndex = 0;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < possibilities.size() ; i++){
                if(Integer.parseInt(possibilities.get(i)[drop]) > lastMaxValue){
                    lastMaxValue = Integer.parseInt(possibilities.get(i)[drop]);
                    lastMaxIndex = i;
                }
            } return possibilities.get(lastMaxIndex);
        }

The problem is that, when I call the function, I see that the "input" is correctly adding the right instructions (String array with any permutation of "left" and "right" plus the sum of the drop), but when the method gets to the return, all of the String arrays in "possibilities" are only going "right" and all have the same sum. My best guess is that this is because when the function gets to the **right** version of **analyzeSlidePath**, setting the String to overwrite "left" to "right" is losing all the instruction data.
```

Example of input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String[]> possibilities = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] strings = new String[4];
        int[][] test = new int[][]{
                {75},
                {95, 64},
                {17, 47, 82},
                {18, 35, 87, 10}};
        String[] myPossibilities = analyzeSlidePath(test, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
        possibilities, strings, 0);
        for(String instruction : myPossibilities){
            System.out.println(instruction);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
[left, left, left, 130]
[left, left, right, 147]
[left, right, left, 177]
[left, right, right, 229]
[right, left, left, 146]
[right, left, right, 198]
[right, right, left, 233]
[right, right, right, 156]
right
right
right
156
```

Expected Output:

```
right
right
left
233
```

Comment: It may help if you [edit] your question and supply sample arguments for method `analyzeSlidePath()` as well as the expected value that the method should return.

Comment: well, with a quick look I see you initialize `input[depth]` twice in a row, so `input[depth]` will always be "right". Please edit your question with examples to help us help you :)